# How to Provision a lot of databases on different devices

Tags: sql, microsoft-sync-framework

Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1
I have one master Database and over 100 devices that will by syncing with the master database.
All databases have existing data on them which is that same data as the master database.
How can I provision one database and restore it on all the other devices and Sync Framework still detecting the changes once users make updates to the records(going in production)?
When I restore a provisioned database, Sync Framework does not see any record change as a change.
Also, is Sync Framework supported with SQL Server 2005 and express?

Comment: what's the database platform are you using on the device? and can you clarify what the device's platform is?

Comment: Database is going to be upgraded from 2005 express to 2012 express. Operating system is Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your client database is SQL Express, provision one database, sync with server, do a backup, restore on client, call performpostrestorefixup one time before synching, then sync as usual.

Comment: so the full picture would be: 1-provision the server database 2-provision the client database 3-sync the two databases 4-call performpostrestorefixup on the client database 5-backup the client database and restore it on other devices. 6-sync as usual.

Comment: 4. backup, 5. restore. 6. performpostrestorefixup, 7. sync.

Comment: The main question I have is do I need to run performpostrestorefixup on all the restored databases every time I restore a database or can I run it on one database and restore that database on all the other devices?

Comment: you have to do the performpostrestorefixup everytime you do a restore.

Comment: I restored a provisioned database, ran performpostrestorefixup on it, changed some records in one of the databases and ran sync.  Changes were not detected and did not get synced.  There has to be a way of restoring a provisioned database and still being able to have the changes tracked.

Comment: enabling Sync Fx tracing so you can see if the changes are being detected and if the are issues applying them. whether you run performpostrestorefixup or now, changes will be tracked if the change tracking triggers are present. but having changes getting tracked doesnt mean they'll get applied.